# How to keep my class output the same and not duplicate it?

Tags: python, class

I wrote a class to make html out of string and some markup tags.

The following is my data:

```
test_string =('1 Then was Jesus led up of the Spirit into the wilderness to be '
              'tempted of the devil.')
test_code = [('equal', 0, 7, 0, 7),
             ('delete', 7, 11, 7, 7),
             ('equal', 11, 15, 7, 11),
             ('insert', 15, 15, 11, 15),
             ('equal', 15, 37, 15, 37),
             ('insert', 37, 37, 37, 38),
             ('equal', 37, 57, 38, 58),
             ('insert', 57, 57, 58, 59),
             ('equal', 57, 64, 59, 66),
             ('replace', 64, 75, 66, 68),
             ('equal', 75, 77, 68, 70),
             ('delete', 77, 78, 70, 70),
             ('equal', 78, 79, 70, 71),
             ('insert', 79, 79, 71, 73),
             ('equal', 79, 80, 73, 74),
             ('delete', 80, 84, 74, 74),
             ('equal', 84, 86, 74, 76)]
```

I intend to write a class to achieve this.

```
output = build_html(test_string,test_code)
output.get_html()
```

### Output:

`"<p class='verse'>1 Then <span class='delete'>was </span>Jesu<span class='insert'></span>s led up of the Spirit<span class='insert'></span> into the wilderness<span class='insert'></span> to be <span class='replace'>tempted of </span>th<span class='delete'>e</span> <span class='insert'></span>d<span class='delete'>evil</span>.</p>"`

This is my code:

```
class build_html():

    def __init__(self, ori_text, opcodes):
        self.text = ""
        self.ori_text = ori_text
        self.opcodes = opcodes

    def makehtml(self, ori_text, code, start, end):
        if code=='equal':
            self.text += ori_text[start:end]
        elif code =='delete':
            self.text += "<span class='delete'>{}</span>".format(ori_text[start:end])
        elif code =='insert':
            self.text += "<span class='insert'>{}</span>".format(ori_text[start:end])
        elif code =='replace':
            self.text += "<span class='replace'>{}</span>".format(ori_text[start:end])

    def get_html(self):
        for modify in self.opcodes:
            self.makehtml(self.ori_text, modify[0],modify[1], modify[2])

        return "<p class='verse'>" + self.text + "</p>"
```

But when every time I do `output.get_html()`, the output was made and appended again. So it will be twice as long.

For example:

```
>>> output.get_html()  # first time
```

`"<p class='verse'>1 Then <span class='delete'>was </span>Jesu<span class='insert'></span>s led up of the Spirit<span class='insert'></span> into the wilderness<span class='insert'></span> to be <span class='replace'>tempted of </span>th<span class='delete'>e</span> <span class='insert'></span>d<span class='delete'>evil</span>.</p>"`

```
>>> output.get_html()   # called second time
```

`"<p class='verse'>1 Then <span class='delete'>was </span>Jesu<span class='insert'></span>s led up of the Spirit<span class='insert'></span> into the wilderness<span class='insert'></span> to be <span class='replace'>tempted of </span>th<span class='delete'>e</span> <span class='insert'></span>d<span class='delete'>evil</span>.</p><p class='verse'>1 Then <span class='delete'>was </span>Jesu<span class='insert'></span>s led up of the Spirit<span class='insert'></span> into the wilderness<span class='insert'></span> to be <span class='replace'>tempted of </span>th<span class='delete'>e</span> <span class='insert'></span>d<span class='delete'>evil</span>.</p>"`

How can I correct it?

Comment: I can't replicate this. Works fine without duplicating

Comment: Works fine with me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to (re)initialize the `self.text` attribute at the beginning of the `get_html()` method so it doesn't contain the results of the last time it was called:

```
    def get_html(self):
        self.text = ""  # ADDED
        for modify in self.opcodes:
            self.makehtml(self.ori_text, modify[0],modify[1], modify[2])

        return "<p class='verse'>" + self.text + "</p>"
```

Comment: Did the error occurs with you ? For me his code works fine. Otherwise, your answer is correct.

Comment: @Chiheb Nexus: Yes, I was able to reproduce the problem the OP described. It's also fairly obvious from just reading the code, IMO. (`output.get_html()` has to be called more than once to reproduce it.)

Comment: @martineau Thank you very much, this is what I expected!

Comment: @Aaron: You're welcome. In the future you should probably put code in your question that actually reproduces the problem. See [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry that I didn't describe well. Hope that I can describe better next time.

Comment: @Aaron: Live and learn. Off-topic - It would be more efficient to make `self.text` a `list` using `self.text = []`, then use `self.text.append(<some string>)` in `makehtml()`, and finally combine them together all at once in `get_html()` with `return "<p class='verse'>" + "".join(self.text) + "</p>"`

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I don't know that before.